# C++ move into container

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I have a class like this:

```
class Object {
   ...
}
```

and a container which essentially consists of a `std::vector<Object>`:

```
class ObjectContainer {
public: 
    void addObject(Object ?? object);
    ...
private:
    std::vector<Object> vector;
}
```

Now after I have initialized an `Object` instance I would like to add the instance to the container and forget about i.e. something like:

```
Container container;
{
    Object object(args...);
    // Maybe more object initialization

    container.addObject( object );
}
```

Now - if possible I would like the container, i.e. `std::vector<Object>` to 'take' the current object instance without any copying - is this possible? And would the implementation of `Container::addObject` be as simple as:

```
void Container::addObject( Object && object) {
   vector.push_back( object );
}
```

Comment: try `container.addObject( std::move(object) );`, keeping the definition as `addObject(Object && object)`

Comment: I assume `Object` is cheap to move otherwise you won't get much benefit from this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wouldn't be quite that simple, you need one more thing:

```
void Container::addObject( Object && object) {
   vector.push_back(std::move(object));
}
```

Within the addObject function, object itself is actually an lvalue, you have to cast it back to an rvalue.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of preparing the object and then move it into the container as the last step, why not create the object inside the container to begin with and the continue messing around with it?

Here is how you would do it with a `std::vector` directly:

```
std::vector<Object> vector;
vector.emplace_back(args...);
Object& object = vector.back();
```

Then you can do further initialization stuff with `object` which is already part of the vector.

Comment: Yes - I might actually do it this way; I know learned about `vector.emplace_back()`- that was new to me. Thank you.